# How to transform non-Gaussian multivariate time series

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, data-transformation, references

I wish to apply a VAR-like kind of model to a multivariate time series dataset. The model assumes that $X_t | X_{t-1} \sim \mathcal{N}(\Gamma X_{t-1},\Omega)$ for $X_t \in \mathbb{R}^p$. I want to learn more about

- how to test this assumption
- if the assumption is not met; if there is any transformation technique that can transform the data so that the conditiona normality assumption is not violated (too much).

Can anyone shed some light in this issue, or reference some resources that might help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want normality? VAR models do not have a normality assumption. You can estimate a VAR model on non-normal data and still get valid coefficient estimates. If you do estimation by OLS, it's just fine. If you do it by maximum likelihood, it will give you quasi-maximum-likelihood estimates, which is still fine.

Comment: I want the assumption to hold, or at least not violated to heavily, because it is one of the assumptions behind the model. However, running multivariate normality tests does not indicate normality in the dataset. Also, the model I'm looking at uses a penalized approach so I'm not looking at OLS or MLE estimates.

Comment: By the way, I do not see *conditional* normality in what you wrote; the $X_{t-1}$ or its properties do not appear anywhere in the distribution. It looks like *unconditional* normality.

Comment: @RichardHardy you're right. I'll edit my question appropriately. By the way, do you have a reference showing the validity of VAR model estimates on non-normal data?

Comment: @RichardHardy I realized I made a mistake in specifying the assumptions. See my edited question.

Comment: Most econometrics textbooks should have the result that normality is not needed for valid VAR estimation. You could try [Lutkepoh's textbook](http://www.springer.com/economics/econometrics/book/978-3-540-40172-8), Chapter 3 (although I cannot guarantee you will find it there). The problem is that assumptions that are **not** used are also less frequently mentioned; hence, it may be difficult to find a statement about normality which is not used... You could think about OLS in general - normality is not assumed there (except for when discussing exact finite sample results).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your **second point**:

A general way to change the distribution of the data could be as follows:

**(1)** obtain the current distribution (e.g. by kernel density estimation);

**(2)** transform your data to uniform distribution using the idea of [probability integral transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform);

**(3)** transform the uniform data to normal by "undoing" the probability integral transform using the normal density.

This works for univariate data, so I guess it should work for multivariate, too.

However, you will need a lot of data for the method to work reasonably well. The higher the dimensionality, the more data you will need. So this need not be the most practical solution...